# Printable div with javascript & form fields

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am using a script that will print the specified div that I call. The problem is that when I want to print out a form with HTML fields, it would not print out information in those fields. Instead, it leaves it blank. Is their a was to make inputted information to be printed as well?

**Javascript**

```
function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="printableArea">
</div>

<input title="Print" class="buttonBlack fl" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" type="submit" value="Print" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/) will help you to print an element and form fields.

Check [samples](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/Sample/). Hope it helps!

Comment: oops! you don't use jQuery, so my answer may not useful I think!

Answer (score 0):

You could of course have a print-only stylesheet that hides everything besides the area that you want to print. Then you wouldn't need any javascript (except maybe `window.print()` for the button). This would have the added benefit of working also when the user prints without using this button.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function printDiv(divName) {
var inpText = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = inpText;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = inpText;
}
```